# Selenium Webdriver No Such Element Found

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

There is `No Such Element Found` even after switching to frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);  
Select numberOfLinesMax = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name(name)));
numberOfLinesMax.selectByVisibleText("sometext");
```

The hierarchy of the element:

[image]

Comment: When you say you're switching frames, are you switching to the iframe, or the frame?  If you want to find the select element, you need to switch to the iframe.

Comment: How to switch to an iframe?

Comment: iframe width="880" scrolling="no" height="90px" frameborder="no" src="multi_archive2.cgi?msisdn=%2B11112&Nbmax=20&ArchiveLevel=Info&StartStop=Start"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're either going to have to use count (starting from 0), or a findElement

I think you can probably use

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

Or, and I think this may be the better solution

```
driver.switchTo().frame(findElement(By.css("form>iframe")));
```

especially if the form has a name or id.

i.e.

If you are going to css select based on form name X, then the css selector will look like this, where X is the name of the form.  You can directly substitute the name for the form where the X is.

`"form.X>iframe"`

by form ID would look like this:

`"form#formID>iframe"`

where formID is the ID of the form.

Comment: can you give a more specific example, supposed there is no id and name for the iframe then we have 'X' as the form name. Thanks Richard

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'someSrc')]"))); I used this and it works. thanks Richard